# Question about the Shannon Entropy formula

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I have a basic question about the Shannon Entropy formula. In fact it's so dumb that I didn't dare ask it in the class because I don't understand the text books.

Here's the formula:

$$H(X) = -\displaystyle\sum_{x} p(x)\log p(x).$$

And here's my question: what function is p(x)? Is it frequency, and if so, frequency of what?

Comment: As the answer says, $p$ is probability.  A reasonable explanation is found in this brochure (pages 2-5): 
https://books.google.com/books?id=Bn2gjlsoi2UC&printsec=frontcover&dq=khinchin+mathematical+foundations+of+information+theory&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVnsC5q4bOAhUM5mMKHUH1C1IQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=entropy&f=false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a probability mass function. In particular, $p(x_0)$ is the probability of event $x_0$ occurring.

Comment: A "[probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)" refers conventionally to continuous random variables, which is not the case here. More correct would be to say that $p(x)$ is a [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) - or simply  "the probability of event $x $ occurring"